# What causes the periodic performance spikes that are seen when doing computationally expensive array processing on the Nexus 4?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, pixel-shader, nexus-4

I'm new to threads (don't kill me for my implementation below :) and I need to do multiple blurring passes of pixels on a separate thread (see below). It's not the most efficient implementation of box blur (it's from [Gaussian Filter without using ConvolveOp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150739/gaussian-filter-without-using-convolveop)) but the performance spikes don't occur on the Nexus 7 tablet but they do occur on the Nexus 4 phone.

I've posted my testing sample (running on Android 4.2 - see below).

I don't think it is caused by the GC thrashing the memory (it doesn't coincide with the spikes).

I think it might be something to do with cache locality or hardware memory thrashing - but I'm not sure.

What would cause the spikes? Sometimes they are sudden onset - e.g. spike of 50%. Sometimes they are slow onset - e.g. spikes increasing/decreasing monotonically, with spikes as follows -> 5%, 10%, 20%, 10%, 5%.

How could I stop them from occurring when doing heavy array processing?

This doesn't occur on the Nexus 7 tablet which I have also tested (see results below)

Side question: What is the best way to sleep and restart my thread correctly (new to threads)?

---

### MainActivity.java

---

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MainThread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        thread = new MainThread();

        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        thread.setRunning(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        thread.setRunning(false);

    }

}
```

---

### MainThread.java

---

```
package com.example.test;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainThread extends Thread {

    int[] pixels;
    int kernel_rows = 2;
    int kernel_cols = 2;
    int width = 512;
    int height = 512;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (running) {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int row = kernel_rows / 2; row < height - kernel_rows / 2; row++) {
                for (int col = kernel_cols / 2; col < width - kernel_cols / 2; col++) {

                    float pixel = 0;

                    // iterate over each pixel in the kernel
                    for (int row_offset = 0; row_offset < kernel_rows; row_offset++) {
                        for (int col_offset = 0; col_offset < kernel_cols; col_offset++) {

                            // subtract by half the kernel size to center the
                            // kernel
                            // on the pixel in question
                            final int row_index = row + row_offset
                                    - kernel_rows / 2;
                            final int col_index = col + col_offset
                                    - kernel_cols / 2;

                            pixel += pixels[row_index * width + col_index] * 1.0f / 4.0f;

                        }
                    }

                    pixels[row * width + col] = (int) pixel;

                }

            }

            long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long delta = stop - start;

            Log.d("DELTA", Long.toString(delta));

        }

    }

    private boolean running;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {

        this.pixels = new int[512 * 512];
        this.running = running;

    }

}
```

---

### Logs

---

**Nexus 4 phone (ms):**

```
01-13 10:56:05.663: D/DELTA(13507): 76
01-13 10:56:05.773: D/DELTA(13507): 107
01-13 10:56:05.843: D/DELTA(13507): 77
01-13 10:56:05.923: D/DELTA(13507): 75
01-13 10:56:06.053: D/DELTA(13507): 127
01-13 10:56:06.133: D/DELTA(13507): 78
01-13 10:56:06.213: D/DELTA(13507): 81
01-13 10:56:06.293: D/DELTA(13507): 80
01-13 10:56:06.353: D/DELTA(13507): 77
01-13 10:56:06.433: D/DELTA(13507): 79
01-13 10:56:06.513: D/DELTA(13507): 79
01-13 10:56:06.624: D/DELTA(13507): 106
01-13 10:56:06.694: D/DELTA(13507): 76
```

**Nexus 7 tablet (ms):**

```
01-13 11:01:03.283: D/DELTA(3909): 84
01-13 11:01:03.373: D/DELTA(3909): 85
01-13 11:01:03.453: D/DELTA(3909): 85
01-13 11:01:03.543: D/DELTA(3909): 84
01-13 11:01:03.623: D/DELTA(3909): 85
01-13 11:01:03.703: D/DELTA(3909): 84
01-13 11:01:03.793: D/DELTA(3909): 85
01-13 11:01:03.873: D/DELTA(3909): 84
01-13 11:01:03.963: D/DELTA(3909): 85
01-13 11:01:04.043: D/DELTA(3909): 84
```

Comment: No idea: Nexus 4 is made from unobtanium.  I bought an S3, not such good value but I could actually buy one.

Comment: Could it be that one has multiple cores while the other doesn't? If there's an idle core, that one will be used to serve the OS and other stuff while one core is computationally busy. That said, having variations of a few tens of milliseconds doesn't seem unusual to me, this is the price we pay for running a preemptive multi-tasking operating system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are both quad core.

Comment: Think I might have mitigated this somewhat with the Android NDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have somewhat mitigated this effect on the Nexus 4. There is still some variability in calculation consistency but it is bearable - I think - can't see too many huge spikes - outside of thread startup/shutdown. I've done this using the Android NDK and c p_threads to spawn a native thread that is mostly left alone by Java (or so I'm told) until the foreground application is changed or closed.

Here is the code:

---

### MainActivity.java

---

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static {

        System.loadLibrary("native");

    }

    private native void init();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initializes and spawns native thread
        init();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

---

### native.c

---

(which should be put into a jni folder at the root of the Android project)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define APPNAME "DELTA"

int* pixels;
int kernel_rows = 2;
int kernel_cols = 2;
int width = 60;
int height = 39;

int running = 1;

// from android samples
/* return current time in milliseconds */
static double now_ms(void) {

    struct timespec res;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res);
    return 1000.0 * res.tv_sec + (double) res.tv_nsec / 1e6;

}

// initialize thread/begin it
jint Java_com_example_testa_MainActivity_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {

    int i1 = 1;

    pthread_t thread;
    void *run();

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run, &i1);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return 0;

}

// thread function
void *run(int *x) {

    // init pixels within thread
    pixels = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);

    // loop until stopped - java won't interfere
    // unless closed/switch application (or so I'm told)
    while (running) {

        double start = now_ms();

        int row, col, row_offset, col_offset;

        for (row = kernel_rows / 2; row < height - kernel_rows / 2; row++) {

            for (col = kernel_cols / 2; col < width - kernel_cols / 2; col++) {

                float pixel = 0;

                // iterate over each pixel in the kernel
                for (row_offset = 0; row_offset < kernel_rows; row_offset++) {
                    for (col_offset = 0; col_offset < kernel_cols;
                            col_offset++) {

                        // subtract by half the kernel size to center the
                        // kernel
                        // on the pixel in question

                        int row_index = row + row_offset - kernel_rows / 2;
                        int col_index = col + col_offset - kernel_cols / 2;

                        pixel += pixels[row_index * width + col_index] * 1.0f
                                / 4.0f;

                    }

                }

                pixels[row * width + col] = (int) pixel;

            }

        }

        double end = now_ms();

        double delta = end - start;

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "%f", delta);

    }

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

---

### Android.mk

---

(which should be put into a jni folder at the root of the Android project)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

### Summary

---

**Reduced cost of code by ~20-30% and decreased variability by an order of magnitude.**

The code is compiled by executing the `ndk-build` command from the NDK library provided by Android at the root folder (found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

---

### Results

---

**Nexus 4 (ms):**

```
01-14 13:41:21.132: V/DELTA(23679): 56.554199
01-14 13:41:21.192: V/DELTA(23679): 58.568604
01-14 13:41:21.252: V/DELTA(23679): 59.484131
01-14 13:41:21.302: V/DELTA(23679): 56.768066
01-14 13:41:21.362: V/DELTA(23679): 54.692383
01-14 13:41:21.412: V/DELTA(23679): 51.823730
01-14 13:41:21.472: V/DELTA(23679): 55.668945
01-14 13:41:21.522: V/DELTA(23679): 56.920654
01-14 13:41:21.582: V/DELTA(23679): 56.371094
01-14 13:41:21.642: V/DELTA(23679): 58.507568
01-14 13:41:21.702: V/DELTA(23679): 59.697754
01-14 13:41:21.752: V/DELTA(23679): 53.990723
01-14 13:41:21.812: V/DELTA(23679): 55.669189
```

**Nexus 7 (ms):**

```
01-14 13:41:25.685: V/DELTA(2916): 65.867920
01-14 13:41:25.745: V/DELTA(2916): 65.986816
01-14 13:41:25.815: V/DELTA(2916): 66.685059
01-14 13:41:25.885: V/DELTA(2916): 67.033936
01-14 13:41:25.945: V/DELTA(2916): 65.703857
01-14 13:41:26.015: V/DELTA(2916): 66.653076
01-14 13:41:26.085: V/DELTA(2916): 66.922119
01-14 13:41:26.145: V/DELTA(2916): 67.030029
01-14 13:41:26.215: V/DELTA(2916): 67.014893
01-14 13:41:26.285: V/DELTA(2916): 67.034912
01-14 13:41:26.345: V/DELTA(2916): 67.089844
01-14 13:41:26.415: V/DELTA(2916): 65.860107
01-14 13:41:26.485: V/DELTA(2916): 65.642090
01-14 13:41:26.545: V/DELTA(2916): 65.574951
01-14 13:41:26.615: V/DELTA(2916): 65.991943
```